# Running Python code from Java program, should i be doing this?

Tags: java, python, jython

i have a scenario where i draw a network and set all it's parameters on swing based GUI, after that i have to translate this network into a python based script which another framework reads and realize this network in the form of virtual machines.

As an example have look here:

```
from mininet.topo import Topo, Node
class MyTopo( Topo ):
    def *__init__*( self, enable_all = True ):
        super( MyTopo, self ).__init__()
        Host = 1
        Switch = 2
        self.add_node( Switch, Node( is_switch=True ) )
        self.add_node( Host, Node( is_switch=False ) )
        self.add_edge( Host, Switch )
        self.enable_all()
topos = { 'mytopo': ( lambda: MyTopo() ) }
```

It simply connects a `host` to a `switch` and realize this topology on a python framework.
Now for now in order to realize the drawn network on Java GUI here is what i am doing:

I simply take the information from GUI and create a new python file like the one above using Java code and then run this file in mininet using `ProcessBuilder` Class in Java, which works fine somehow.

I want to know, is this the correct and robust way how i am doing this or should i be looking further into java-python bridge like scenarios to be more effective or so as to say more professional.

**EDIT:**

The options i was wondering are:

1. Serialize the GUI in a well known format (yaml maybe?) that can be deserialized by python and then add additional functionality in python to pass that information to this script.
2. Add a Java-Python bridge to do this directly from within the code??
3. Any other idea?     What should i do, or im good at whatever is being done here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using an easy to read cross language data format like JSON. Python and Java have excellent support for JSON. I have done integration between PHP, Java, and Python using this technique. What you have done is something like [code generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_programming) which is also a valid approach but has it's cons. Here are a few pros/cons off the top of my head of the two approaches:

**Code Generation Pros/Cons**

- Can at times be easy to implement
- Security issues, one program is generating code to execute in another environment, the python code could run any command
- No validation, if your code generation library has a bug there is no way to validate it's output, because it's not a data structure. Potential security issues here again.
- Very powerful you can essentially run any python code from your java library

**Data Exchange(JSON) Pros/Cons**

- Can be validated to catch any data corruption or bugs in generation
- Better security parsing JSON in python doesn't execute any code it just loads a data structure
- Can be easier to view especially if you [pretty print json in python](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)
- requires you to decide on some data structure to map your nodes to JSON
- you will have to write something to take that data structure and produce your Topo and Node objects from it.

Comment: Data exchange also lets the two programs' implementations evolve independently: one could even decide to rewrite one of the two in another language!

Answer (score 0):

If your Python code was dependant on pure Python libs then you could use [embedded Jython](http://wiki.python.org/jython/LearningJython#embedding-jython-into-java).

My preference would be your first option to serialise the configuration to an agnostic format. 
Writing Python source code from Java will be difficult to maintain.

If you decided to serialise, consider using JAXB or similar with an XML schema on the Java side to build a rigid data exchange format in XML. You can then use PyXB to convert the XML back into Python objects.